# How to restrict Typescript generic function to objects containing variadic method of a certain name and parameterization?

Tags: typescript, generics

Honestly, I wasn't even sure how to word this question. I want to write a function that takes an object and calls a variadic method by name in such a way that typescript is checking that both the method name exists on the type and the function parameters are correct.

Bellow is not valid Typescript. I'm looking for something that is.

```js
const thing = {
    add: function(x: number, y: number) { return x + y },
    inc: function(x: number) { return x + 1 },
}

function test<T extends { K: (...args: Args) => R }, K extends keyof T, Args extends any[], R>(obj: T, key: K, ...args: Args) {
    return obj[key](...args)
}

test(thing, "add", 2, 2)   //OK
test(thing, "inc", 2)      //OK
test(thing, "foo", 2, 2)   //BAD
test(thing, "add", 2, "a") //BAD
```

Answer (score -1):

here's the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFAWBLMBzGBeGBvAUDfMAhgCbEBcMAZgK5jBSLgAUAHhWNQLYBGApgE4AaGAE92XPvwCU2GP15Rq-MDBYwA1KJgBfQXgLJgFGnQbM2MDjwEyschUpVrNARh16CMaP24gQAG2NaekYwJkIKb2QUYW4KXwDeQjBbeUVlIg0Ybl19fF5OAAcoMSpgszDUhwyXACYAZm0cJpwcExDwOF5oAB4AFRheFiheMGIIGAAlXlB+Yh6o1GEmADo1wn4UCApkkQBtAF0ZdAA+IjARE+EAaUHh0fGYAGteERBKGD6TphBuACsKH1hC9StdhGsVhsthQAAobQicBQCCD9PbXA4nKQUabpMB9ESFXio9FnXCeNKOGC-P57EEHVbrTYQKTNVqgSCwWCYEbQJgIaLCABEJGIguEtXFMnwAHppQB5a44HlQPlIJYwQWGMUwWpSzyyhVK7oq-nqgDk3gS-jNwgtUH4Nrg-GovBkBsVytVApgZoKxREZrd0pghs9ppiGr9JW1tGIvEoyF4xCDMAAQgBBAAiRt54aFlD82olOr1soz2bDaojwtIRaFhEFQfLQA)

don't hesitate to ask questions if any arise

UPDATE:
I managed to simplify the solution and it seems to work for all the cases now

Comment: My apologies. I downvoted you because I thought your answer was being obtuse or snide because I mistakenly believed you had posted a playground with the exact (incorrect) code I had provided in my question. Can you please make an edit to your question so that stackoverflow will allow me to change my vote to and upvote and accept your answer?

Comment: I updated the question because it looks like this breaks if the object contains many methods/members that aren't all exactly fitting `(number, number) => number`. I need a more general solution that would work with more complex types that aren't simply a map from type A to type B.